# No such element exception error?

Tags: java, exception, element

I'm writing a program that will print out letter grades, and an average based on what it reads from a text file I set up. The text file already has some sample numbers in it (integers).

It compiles, but when I run it it highlights the "int grade = in.nextInt();" line and gives me the following error:

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Prog2.main(Prog2.java:26)
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
public class Prog2
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("prog2test.txt")); 
   int scores = (in.nextInt());
   int A = 0;
   int B = 0;
   int C = 0;
   int D = 0;
   int F = 0;

   while (scores > 0)
   {
      int grade = in.nextInt();
      if (grade >= 90)
      {
         A++;
      }
      else if (grade >= 80)
      {
         B++;
      }
      else if (grade >= 70)
      {
         C++;
      }
      else if (grade >= 60)
      {
         D++;
      }
      else
      {
         F++;
      }

      scores = scores--;
   }  
   scores = 0;
   while (scores > 0)
   {
      System.out.println(in.nextInt());
      scores--;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: I think, it cannot find the prog2test.txt

Comment: if ((sourceClosed) && (position == buf.limit()))
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

Comment: So guess 1. as gjman said, 2. there can't find token,position is at end of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether there is another integer to read with `in.hasNextInt()` as the while loop condition.

Comment: What do you meant by as the while loop condition? Instead of the current "scores > 0" one?

Comment: I'm guessing that score is the number of scores that are going to be parsed in. The while loop should be while(score > 0 && in.hasNextInt()) which ensures that it will only try to scan if there is another integer (so nextInt won't throw a NoSuchElementException, which is when it tries to scan something that isn't there)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this... while you are printing out variable... you are putting, `in.nextInt()` without any check... do some RnD there... however, this code prints some arbitrary results.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Prog2
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("prog2test.txt")); 
        int scores = (in.nextInt());
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int C = 0;
        int D = 0;
        int F = 0;

        while (scores > 0&& in.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            if (grade >= 90)
            {
                A++;
            }
            else if (grade >= 80)
            {
                B++;
            }
            else if (grade >= 70)
            {
                C++;
            }
            else if (grade >= 60)
            {
                D++;
            }
            else
            {
                F++;
            }

            scores = scores--;
        }  

        //scores = 0;
        while (scores > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(scores);
            scores--;
        }
    }
}
```